# How to Move Current Editor (Tab) to the Beginning or End of Current Editor Group

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found `View: Move Editor Left` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd>) and `View: Move Editor Right` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PageDown</kbd>) to move current Editor to the left or right.

However, I could not find any option to Move current Editor (Tab) at the Beginning or End of Current Editor Group. Similar to Firefox's `Move Tab > Move To Start` and `Move Tab > Move To End`.

How can I move current Editor (Tab) to the beginning or end of current Editor Group?

Comment: asked a question on  Sep 21, 2021, answered my question in Oct 4, 2021, then the bot figured out that my question is the duplicate of the reference I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP Here,

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+pageup",
    "command": "moveActiveEditor",
    "args": {
        "to": "left",
        "by": "tab",
        "value": 25
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+pagedown",
    "command": "moveActiveEditor",
    "args": {
        "to": "right",
        "by": "tab",
        "value": 25
    }
},
```

Please check, [Alex's answer to Visual Studio Code: Hotkey to move a tab from its current location to the very front?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54053581/1772898) for more details.